# C++ double pointer output

Tags: c++, pointers

C++ noob have a question why my code works one way but not there other.. I have a single book class with a constructor that takes a single int parameter and sets it to pages (i.e number of pages in the book). i also have a main.cpp.

book.h :

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Book{
  public:
    Book(int);
    int pages;
};

#endif
```

Book.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

Book::Book(int t){
  pages = t;
}
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 #include "Book.h"

Book** elements;
int size = 0;
int add(Book* b);

int main()
{

  Book* b1 = new Book(99);
  Book* b2 = new Book(100);
  Book* b3 = new Book(101);
  Book* b4 = new Book(102);

  add (b1);
  add (b2);
  add (b3);
  add (b4);

 //***I get garbage values printed here***
  cout << " pages " << elements[0]->pages << "\n";
  cout << " pages " << elements[1]->pages << "\n";
  cout << " pages " << elements[2]->pages << "\n";
  cout << " pages " << elements[3]->pages << "\n";

  //delete the books
  delete b1;
  delete b2;
  delete b3;
  delete b4;

  return 0;
}

int add(Book* b)
{
  Book* newList[size+1];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     newList[i] = elements[i];
  }
  delete elements;
  newList[size] =  b;
  elements = newList;

  //***i get correct values printed here ***
  cout << " pages in function: " << elements[size]->pages << "\n";

  size++;
  return 1;
}
```

my question is why are the pages able to be printed when I print them inside the function 'add' but I get garbage values when I print them outside.

my output is as follows:
`pages in function: 99
pages in function: 100
pages in function: 101
pages in function: 102
pages 2293484
pages 4667584
pages 4667584
pages 4667584`

where as output SHOULD be: 
`pages in function: 99
pages in function: 100
pages in function: 101
pages in function: 102
pages 99
pages 100
pages 101
pages 102`

Comment: No external link please. You can add code to the question. It is very hard to read your question.

Comment: This isn't the answer but note you can make the `add()` function more simple. You can just check if there's no room for add your element, if so, call `realloc()` (don't forget to use return value of it) and then ` elements[size++] =  b;` will be fine. The check for room can be done as following: `if(size + 1 > elements_size) { elements_size += 1; elements = realloc(elements, elements_size); }` and then `elements[size++] =  b;` will be valid because there's enough room to store the pointer so you don't need that loop.

Comment: `realloc()` does basically the job you're doing with your loop + delete.

Comment: You have a whole ton of uninitialised pointers here, not to mention the wrong `delete`. What's wrong with vectors?

Comment: I haven't test and I don't do C/C++ for a while but it might work: http://pastebin.com/rAhiFTJ6 the goal is give you the idea how to implement your add() with realloc()

Answer (score 1):

`newlist[i] = elements[i]` only assigns the pointer at `elements[i]` to `newlist[i]`. Later, you called `delete` and the object pointed by `elements[i]` (and also pointed by `newlist[i]`) is gone. So you get random values outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is that `newList` is a local array, so it gets destroyed as soon as `add` exits.

Since `add` changes `elements` to point at `newList`, that means `elements` is always pointing to garbage after a call to `add`.

(if this is anything but a deliberate exercise in working with pointers, you really ought to be using standard data structures instead, like `std::vector` whose primary purpose in life is to be a resizable array)